# making menu and sub-menu python

Tags: python, if-statement, state-machine

I'm learning to make menus in python using the statemachine module,

here is the code i ran and it works fine

```
from statemachine import State, StateMachine

class MenuStateMachine(StateMachine):
    # States
    main_menu = State('Main Menu', initial=True)
    menu1 = State('Option1')
    menu2 = State('Option2')

    submenu1 = State('Sub-Menu1')
    
    # Transitions
    select_menu1 = main_menu.to(menu1)
    select_menu2 = main_menu.to(menu2)
    select_submenu1 = menu1.to(submenu1)
    back_to_main_menu = menu1.to(main_menu) | menu2.to(main_menu)
    back_to_menu1 = submenu1.to(menu1)

    def on_main_menu(self):
        print('=== Main Menu ===')
        print('[1] Option1')
        print('[2] Option2')
        print('[3] Exit')

    def on_menu1(self):
        print('=== Option1 Menu ===')
        print('[1] SubOption1')
        print('[2] SubOption2')
        print('[3] SubOption3')
        print('[4] Previous Menu')

    def on_submenu1(self):
        print('=== SubOption1 Menu ===')
        print('[1] Act1')
        print('[2] Act2')
        print('[3] Act3')
        print('[4] Previous Menu')

    def on_menu2(self):
        print('=== Option2 Menu ===')
        print('[1] Previous Menu')

# Create an instance of the MenuStateMachine class
menu = MenuStateMachine()

# Start the menu state machine
while True:
    menu.on_main_menu()
    choice = input('Enter Choice: ')

    if choice == '1':
        menu.select_menu1()
        while menu.current_state.id == 'menu1':
            menu.on_menu1()
            menu_choice = input('Enter Choice : ')
            if menu_choice == '1':
                menu.select_submenu1()
                while menu.current_state.id == 'submenu1':
                    menu.on_submenu1()
                    submenu_choice = input('Enter Choice : ')
                    if submenu_choice == '1':
                        print('Do Something Here')
                        break
                    elif submenu_choice == '2':
                        print('Do Something Here')
                        break
                    elif submenu_choice == '3':
                        print('Do Something Here')
                        break                       
                    elif submenu_choice == '4':
                        menu.back_to_menu1()
                    else:
                        print('Invalid choice. Please try again.')
            elif menu_choice == '4':
                menu.back_to_main_menu()
            elif menu_choice in ['2','3']:
                print('There is no menu yet, please choose another')
            else:
                print('Invalid choice. Please try again.')
    elif choice == '2':
        menu.select_menu2()
        menu.on_menu2()
        menu_choice = input('Enter Choice : ')
        if menu_choice == '1':
            menu.back_to_main_menu()
        else:
            print('Invalid choice. Please try again.')
    elif choice == '3':
        print('=== Exit ===')
        exit()
    else:
        print("Invalid choice. Please try again.")
```

but I imagine that my code can be improved to be better, I think my code is not efficient especially the use of if and while. If there are a lot of sub menus or sub-sub menus will look messy, and I think this can be improved even better, any suggestions to improve my code?

Comment: I think it could possibly make the code more readable if you used [match Statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=match%20case#match-statements)

Comment: You could use dictionaries and functions, I'll post an answer with the code sample